# Selecting an item matching multiple tags

Tags: sql, mysql, many-to-many

This seems very basic but I can't figure it out.

I've got a table "item_tags", and I want to select all of the items that match tags 1 and 2 (as in, each item has to have both tags).

How would I do this in mysql?

Create table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `item_tags` (
  `uid_local` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `uid_foreign` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sorting` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `uid_local` (`uid_local`),
  KEY `uid_foreign` (`uid_foreign`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where are the items, and what is tag 1 and tag 2?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT i.uid
    FROM ITEMS i
    JOIN ITEM_TAGS it ON it.uid_local = i.uid
                   AND it.uid_foreign IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY i.uid
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT it.uid_foreign) = 2
```

You need to have a GROUP BY and HAVING clause defined, and the count of distinct tag ids must equal the number of tags you specify in the IN clause.

Comment: Wouldn't this query have to handle all the rows until it calculates the `COUNT` value? I was wondering if there's a way where it eliminates the unmatched as it goes. Maybe `INNER JOIN` statements could be utilized by joining the tag table to itself for each tag while adding the tag match to the `ON` statement instead of `WHERE`.  It will have to look up the entire table again for each tag though. Idk how much it would help having indexed the tag ids. I'mma go run some experiments

Comment: I did. It was a horrible idea. Took roughly 4 times the query in the answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
SELECT i.* from items i inner join items_tags it
on i.id = it.item_id
inner join tags t
on t.id = it.tag_id
WHERE t.name in ('tag1', 'tag2');
```

**EDIT:**

suppouse you have items_tags: (item_id, tag_id) as table

Comment: This aproach would be an OR match rather than an AND match, so it doesn't answer the question.
 i.e. this query will find items that match tag1 or tag2.. and also potentially return duplicate items. The question wanted to only  find items that had both tag1 AND tag2