# Sql query to find things with most specified tags

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails, tags, tagging

Let's say I have the following tables:

### TAGS

id: integer
name: string

### POSTS

id: integer
body: text

### TAGGINGS

id: integer
tag_id: integer
post_id: integer

How would I go about writing a query that selects all posts in order of the post containing the highest number of the following tags (name attribute of tags table): "Cheese", "Wine", "Paris", "Frace", "City", "Scenic", "Art"

See also: [Sql query to find things tagged with all specified tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876240) (note: similar, but not a duplicate!)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, please stop voting to close it as such.

Comment: Correct @OMG Ponies .... I know it's the same data, but I need to do two very different things with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike your linked question, you did not specify here that you needed to match ALL tags. This query works for ANY.

```
SELECT p.id, p.text, count(tg.id) as TagCount
    FROM Posts p 
        INNER JOIN Taggings tg 
            ON p.id = tg.post_id
        INNER JOIN Tags t 
            ON tg.tag_id = t.id
    WHERE t.name in ('Cheese', 'Wine', 'Paris', 'Frace', 'City', 'Scenic', 'Art')
    GROUP BY p.id, p.text
    ORDER BY TagCount DESC
```

Comment: correct, they do not need to match all... just return first the one that matchs more than others

Comment: In reality, I actually have many more fields on post than just id and text... is there a way to make it return all the fields without specifying each in the query? Maybe p.*? I'm not a sql expert.

Comment: Don't use * in your queries. List all the columns you need in both the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Why? I need to use all of the columns.

Comment: There are several reasons why `SELECT *` is a bad idea. One of the key ones is that you limit the optimizer's ability to choose an appropriate index. See [here](http://dotnethitman.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!E149A8B1E1C25B14!204.entry). Also, for code stability, if someone should alter the POSTS table in the future and add a new column, your `SELECT *` is going to pick it up and probably break your application that was expecting to get back 2 columns and is now getting 3 returned.

Comment: I see... I'm used to using ruby on rails where sql is usually generated and by default uses *

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
   Select p.Id, p.Text, Count(*)
   From Posts p 
      Left Join (Taggings tg Join Tags t 
                    On t.Tag_Id = tg.Tag_Id
                       And t.name in     
                        ('Cheese', 'Wine', 'Paris', 
                         'Frace', 'City', 'Scenic', 'Art'))
         On tg.Post_Id = p.Post_Id
   Group By p.Id, p.text  
   Order By Count(*) Desc
```