# MySql: Select items what have all the values

Tags: mysql

I have Mysql table with 3 columns: id, company_id and tag_id.
It's used to link companies and tags together.
Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_company_tag_link (
  id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  company_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  tag_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Any company can be linked with any number of tags.
I need to select companies, that have ALL of the specified tags attached.
For example, I need company_id that have tag_id = 1,2,3 (all of them!)
The query that I came to is ugly:

```
SELECT company_id, GROUP_CONCAT(tag_id) as group_concat_tag_id
FROM tbl_company_tag_link
WHERE tag_id IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY company_id
HAVING group_concat_tag_id = "1,2,3"
```

I need help with writing query, that would be fast.

I've created sqlfiddle with my schema and query for fast testing: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2416f/2

too late, found the same question with detailed answers: [Need help with sql query to find things tagged with all specified tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876240/need-help-with-sql-query-to-find-things-tagged-with-all-specified-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT company_id
FROM tbl_company_tag_link
WHERE tag_id IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY company_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id ) = 3
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2416f/12)**

Answer (score 0):

SQL Fiddle doesn't load but you can give this a try:

```
SELECT company_id, GROUP_CONCAT(tag_id) as group_concat_tag_id
FROM tbl_company_tag_link
WHERE tag_id IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY company_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3;
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, it works, but Rahul Tripathi's answer is more complete, because of DISTINCT.

Comment: No problem. I just upvoted for his answer because i know it's better.