# Prisma 2 query to return records only that are associated with ALL of the provided tag IDs

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-server, prisma, prisma-graphql, redwoodjs

I have tables Principles and Tags. And there is a many-to-many relation between them ([joined implicitly](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-schema/relations#implicit-many-to-many-relations)).

Without using `prisma.raw`, how can I run the following query?

```sql
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.description, p.createdAt, p.modifiedAt
    FROM principle p
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                   FROM _PrincipleToTag pt
                  WHERE pt.B IN (${tagIds.join(',')})
                    AND pt.A = p.id
               GROUP BY pt.A
                 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pt.B) = ${tagIds.length})
```

**How can I update this Prisma 2 query such that the principles returned are only principles that are associated with ALL of the provided tagIds?**

```js
export const principles = ({ tagIds }) => {
  const payload = {
    where: {
      //TODO filter based on tagIds
    },
  }
  return db.principle.findMany(payload)
}
```

[The docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-client/filtering#filter-on-related-records) mention `contains` and `in` and `every`, but I can't find examples of what I'm trying to do.

I'm using RedwoodJs, Prisma 2, Apollo, GraphQL.

---

**Update** in response to comment: here is the SDL:

```js
input CreatePrincipleInput {
  title: String!
  description: String
}

input CreatePrincipleWithTagsInput {
  title: String!
  description: String
  tagIdsJson: String
}

input CreateTagInput {
  title: String!
  description: String
}

# A date string, such as 2007-12-03, compliant with the `full-date` format
# outlined in section 5.6 of the RFC 3339 profile of the ISO 8601 standard for
# representation of dates and times using the Gregorian calendar.
scalar Date

# A date-time string at UTC, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30Z, compliant with the
# `date-time` format outlined in section 5.6 of the RFC 3339 profile of the ISO
# 8601 standard for representation of dates and times using the Gregorian calendar.
scalar DateTime

type Mutation {
  createPrinciple(input: CreatePrincipleInput!): Principle
  createPrincipleWithTags(input: CreatePrincipleWithTagsInput!): Principle
  updatePrinciple(id: Int!, input: UpdatePrincipleInput!): Principle!
  deletePrinciple(id: Int!): Principle!
  createTag(input: CreateTagInput!): Tag!
  updateTag(id: Int!, input: UpdateTagInput!): Tag!
  deleteTag(id: Int!): Tag!
}

type Principle {
  id: Int!
  title: String!
  description: String!
  tags: [Tag]
  createdAt: DateTime!
  modifiedAt: DateTime!
}

type Query {
  redwood: Redwood
  principles(searchQuery: String, tagIds: [Int]): [Principle!]!
  tags: [Tag!]!
  tagsByLabel(searchTerm: String): [TagCount!]!
  tag(id: Int!): Tag!
}

type Redwood {
  version: String
}

type Tag {
  id: Int!
  title: String!
  principles: [Principle]
  description: String
  createdAt: DateTime!
  modifiedAt: DateTime!
}

type TagCount {
  id: Int!
  title: String!
  count: Int!
  principles: [Principle]
  description: String
  createdAt: DateTime!
  modifiedAt: DateTime!
}

# A time string at UTC, such as 10:15:30Z, compliant with the `full-time` format
# outlined in section 5.6 of the RFC 3339profile of the ISO 8601 standard for
# representation of dates and times using the Gregorian calendar.
scalar Time

input UpdatePrincipleInput {
  title: String
  description: String
}

input UpdateTagInput {
  title: String
  description: String
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are using prisma 2. Prisma 2 uses models (not types) and has arrays classified like Principles[] vs [Principles]. Maybe Redwood does the conversion(Never used it).

I created your model in Prisma 2 and used the following command to get a single principle that has the two tags associated with it. Keep in mind the IDs in there are from my test dataset. Hopefully, you can modify this to your code. If not, please create a sandbox/playground with minimal code for us to test.

```
export const principles = async ({ searchQuery, tagIds }) => {      
  const payload = {
    where: {
      OR: [
        { title: { contains: searchQuery } },
        { description: { contains: searchQuery } },
      ],
      userId: userIdFromSession,
    },
  }
  if (tagIds.length) {
    const whereAnd = []
    tagIds.forEach((tagId) => {
      whereAnd.push({
        tags: { some: { id: tagId } },
      })
    })
    payload.where.AND = whereAnd
  }
  const result = await db.principle.findMany(payload)
  return result
}
```

Comment: I get error "Unknown arg `tagId_some` in where.AND.0.tagId_some for type PrincipleWhereInput." when I use this `const whereAnd = []
    tagIds.forEach((tagId) => {
      whereAnd.push({
        tagId_some: { tagId: tagId },
      })
    })`

Comment: can you post your graphql schema from your playground

Comment: I updated my question to add the GraphQL schema. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: Any last ideas? I'm supposed to award the bounty soon. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you! I adjusted your answer to what I'm using now, and it seems to work! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this

```js
export const principles = ({ searchQuery, tagIds }) => {
  const payload = {
    where: {
      OR: [
        { title: { contains: searchQuery } },
        { description: { contains: searchQuery } },
      ],
      // using the `in` operator like this
      tagId: { in: tagIds },
      userId: userIdFromSession,
    },
  }
  console.log('db.principle.findMany(payload)', payload)
  return db.principle.findMany(payload)
}
```

That should do the trick!

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I tried it and updated my question with the error message. I'd love to hear any other ideas if you have a moment. Thanks again!

Comment: You would have to use `tags` as per your model. `tagId` was just a placeholder as I wasn't aware of your model field. Sorry for not mentioning that earlier.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but this still isn't correct. I'd think I'd need to use both `every` and `in`, maybe like this: `{"where":{"OR":[{"title":{"contains":""}},{"description":{"contains":""}}],"userId":1,"tag":{"every":[{"id":{"in":[9,6]}},{"id":{"in":[9,6]}}]}}}` either with `tag` singular or `tags` plural. But I'm getting errors "Unknown arg `tag` in where.tag for type PrincipleWhereInput" or "Unknown arg `0` in where.tags.every.0 for type TagWhereInput."

Comment: I simplified my question above by showing the raw query that is the equivalent of what I'm trying to achieve. As https://stackoverflow.com/a/3876276/470749 explains, it allows me to retrieve only principles that are associated with *all* of the supplied tagIds. If you have any ideas, I'd appreciate them. Thanks.

Comment: How about this one?

`db.principle.findMany({
    where: {
      OR: [
        {
          title: { contains: searchQuery },
        },
        {
          description: { contains: searchQuery },
        },
      ],
      tags: {
        every: {
          id: {
            in: tagIds,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  })`

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. That query runs without error, but the result isn't what I'm hoping for. I'll add a bounty to this question. I'd really like to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

I had to resort to using `AND` for something similar - hope this helps!

```js
const tagIds = [9,6];

where: {
  // ...
  AND: tagIds.map(tagId => ({
    tags: {
      some: {
        id: {
          equals: tagId,
        },
      },
    },
  })),
}
```