# Return rows that have a specific column in common while containing the same column values

Tags: sql

I'm sorry, i'm not really sure how to phrase this question properly. Here's an example of what i'm talking about:

```
#       food   type
1       muffin vegan
2       pasta  vegan     
3       cookie vegan     
4       burger vegan
5       bread  idk
6       boba   idk
7       muffin ok
8       pasta  ok
9       muffin no
10      pasta  yes
11      muffin hi
```

So I want to return all the rows that contain muffin & pasta that have the same type as well. So if my query was correct, this would be returned:

## food   type

```
1       muffin vegan
2       pasta  vegan  
3       cookie vegan     
4       burger vegan   
7       muffin ok
8       pasta  ok
```

How do I do this?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting an item matching multiple tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119840/selecting-an-item-matching-multiple-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from T where type in (
    select type from T
    where food in ('muffin', 'pasta')
    group by type
    having count(distinct food) = 2
);
```