# Finding items that match multiple LIKE keywords

Tags: sqlite, pattern-matching, many-to-many, relational-database

In a many to many relationship like these given tables:
1-pizza id, name
2-topping id, name
3-pizza_topping pid,tid  (pid references pizza(id), tid references toppind (id))

I want to search for pizzas, depending on multiple not exactly named toppings. So all matches are dependent on user input and not exact. So he needs to say can say I want pizzas with all the topping not starting with 'q' and does not include mushroom.

In short, I will specify multiple patterns of names for the toppings I want. And the pizza must have all those toppings (Can't be just one of them). I have seen answers that use DISTINT, IN and HAVING COUNT , in many various forms like this [Selecting an item matching multiple tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119840/selecting-an-item-matching-multiple-tags)
and more. But this will not work because the strings supplied are supposed to be matched with 'LIKE' due to them possibly being a pattern, so I can't match with in.
And their count will not solve it (finding 'a%' will have different counts for each pizza, and when combined with other queries that can be equal. The count could be misleading because the 'a%' makes it match multiple times).

I've tried to auto formulate AND OR and NOT for the search condition given keyword and patterns for a query and translate them into this (This is not exactly the example above) :

```
SELECT p.* FROM Pizza p
JOIN PizzaToppping pt ON p.ID = pt.PizzaID
WHERE pt.ToppingID IN (SELECT ID FROM Toppings WHERE name LIKE 'a%')
     AND pt.ToppingID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Toppings WHERE name LIKE 'mushroom')
     AND pt.ToppingID IN (SELECT ID FROM Toppings WHERE name LIKE 'tuna%' OR name LIKE '%fish')
```

And I've tried using SELECT DISTINCT. But the issue is it seems to be getting the queries like a cross-product (which I partially understand but cant fix), and the DISTINCT eliminates repition but acts like a union of the set of results.

Is there a short way to write the query with the multiple patterns of words I'll search with. Or do I have to do something like this (I have not tested this, I don't know if it works correctly BTW):

```
SELECT p.* FROM Pizza p
    JOIN PizzaToppping pt ON p.ID = pt.PizzaID
    WHERE pt.ToppingID IN (SELECT ID FROM Toppings WHERE name LIKE 'a%')
INTERSECT
    SELECT p.*
    FROM Pizza p
    JOIN PizzaToppping pt ON p.ID = pt.PizzaID
    pt.ToppingID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Toppings WHERE name LIKE 'mushroom')
INTERSECT
    SELECT p.*
    FROM Pizza p
    JOIN PizzaToppping pt ON p.ID = pt.PizzaID
         pt.ToppingID IN (SELECT ID FROM Toppings WHERE name LIKE 'tuna%' OR name LIKE '%fish');
```

Note: I am using sqlite.
Also is there a more efficient way (if the intersection is the answer)?